# Are custom firebase ecommerce events possible?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, google-analytics, e-commerce

There are some event names marked as ecommerce like "purchase", "refund" etc. When you send these events, you can send "Items" array and see "event_value_usd" column in BigQuery that is auto-converted through your "value" and "currency" params.

Is it possible to send custom events for example "subsription_renewal" event that can be processed like an ecommerce event on google analytics?